# Spot light shows dimly through solid plane

Tags: light

I'm attempting to shine a spot light through text that has been cut out of a plane. The effect works pretty well, but some of the light from the spot light that is behind the plane shows through as seen in this picture:

[image]

The plane uses default settings and has no material or texture associated with it, though adding a solid black material has no effect on the render.

Lamp is set to Spot, Buffer Shadow, Halo, Step=1, Distance=10, Size=130.  Other settings are pretty much the default settings.

I've been playing with this for hours and can't seem to figure this one out.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Have u trien switching on ray shadow?

Comment: Is it possible you could upload a .blend demonstrating this behavior?

Comment: Ray shadow does not give the right effect.  Here is a link to a dropbox folder containing the .blend file.  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/05831purpzk4x62/AAD4t7fO7uIvjs7sqrwAXnmZa?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

I think is the blocking object, it's 2D. Try to get another one starting from a 3d even slightly extruded plane (extruding your gives me weird results), carving out the text. Then you might need a slightly more powerful (energy) spot, but in this way I got it working.

[image]

Comment: just add a solidify modifier.

Comment: Looks like both of these solutions will work, but the modifier may be the easiest for my case.  Thanks!

Comment: Just tested.  Modifier worked great and was a quick solution.

Comment: @Aaron you should accept this answer (click the green checkmark) if it was the right answer.

Comment: No, I think he already chose the other one, using the solidify modifier to get the same result (i remember that answer) but now... is no more? weird.